# IE10 (in compatibility mode) generates SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant error on valid code?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a few small JQuery scripts in SharePoint that currently use hard-coded paths to include jquery itself and CSS, so they are a pain to move around.

I thought i'd use JS and document.write() to include the files using dynamically generated paths including the site root URL.

Problem: I have a piece of what I think is valid JS code, but IE10 spits it out with an "unterminated string" error. if I change the final `'</script>'` string to anything else it works ok (but of course doesn't result in valid html).

The code itself passes JSlint with a few comments about spacing. Javascriptlint.com generates a warning about "script tag must be empty if a path is specified", but I can fix that by setting the variable "imp" in two lines, firstly generating the `link`tag, then concatenating the `script` tag.

Code:

```
<script language="javascript">

  var siteURL= L_Menu_BaseUrl;

  var imp= '<link href="' + siteURL + '/SiteAssets/Path/my.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>\n'
  +        '<script language="javascript" src="' + siteURL + '/lib/js/jquery-1.9.1_min.js">' + '</script>\n';

</script>
```

I have been staring at this too long, it's probably something really simple. I'm just building an HTML string here but IE seems to be interpreting the final `</script>` tag, ignoring the fact that it's a literal string in quotes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Change `+ '</script>\n';` to `+ '</scr'+'ipt>\n';`.

Comment: As far as I know, `\n` does not do anything in HTML. You'll need to replace it with `<br>` (or `<br />` for XHTML)...

Comment: Thanks. Exactly WHY IE insists on interpreting the script close tag when syntactically it's in a string is unclear. Maybe they are trying to make the browser more robust to scripts with unmatched quotes?!

BTW I know the \n doesn't do anything (other than add a space) in HTML terms, I was just trying to keep the generated HTML (to be injected with document.write() in the same format as readable HTML.

Answer (score 3):

> IE seems to be interpreting the final `</script>` tag, ignoring the fact that it's a literal string in quotes

This is exactly what's happening.  One solution is to use `'</scr'+'ipt>'`.  Just break up the closing tag, so it's not interpreted as a close tag.

```
  var imp= '<link href="' + siteURL + '/SiteAssets/Path/my.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>\n'
  +        '<script language="javascript" src="' + siteURL + '/lib/js/jquery-1.9.1_min.js">' + '</scr' + 'ipt>\n';
```

EDIT: You can also just do this

```
... + '<\/script>\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the helpful comments. Having done more reading on this issue I came to the understanding that using `document.write()` is generally considered bad practice, or at least something to be avoided.

You can create the `<link> and <script>` tags entirely in JS code, but that ends up being pretty verbose. I also found it added a layout glitch to my page as the various bits of code wrote the tags that loaded JQuery and the CSS and THEN the browser could finally lay out the page correctly.

I ended up with a hybrid approach, using HTML tags to load the default (production site) location of the dependency files, but then having the script tweak the file paths for the dev site (where a slight layout delay is tolerable).

The result looks like-

```
<link id="MyCSS" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sites/live/SiteAssets/Path/my.css"/>
<script id="JQ" language="javascript" src="/sites/live/lib/js/jquery-1.9.1_min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript"> 
/*
 * Paths for dev / debug
 */
var siteURL= L_Menu_BaseUrl;

if( siteURL != "/sites/live" ) {
    document.getElementById("MyCSS").href=
            siteURL + "/SiteAssets/Path/my.css";
    document.getElementById("JQ").src=
            siteURL + "/lib/js/jquery-1.9.1_min.js";
}
</script>
```